# Share feature on Area 51

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, area-51

After flushing my cookies today, I notice that the 'share' link which brings up a box of social networks is not working very well, at least with Twitter.

First, twitter is opened in the same window. After posting, I have to open a new tab and go back to Area 51.

Secondly, if you aren't logged into twitter, the link is not carried through after signing in. Again, you have to open a new tab, go back to Area51, get the link then post it.

If all of this happened in a new tab / window by default, it would not be so noticeable.

Comment: Yes, this is a bit annoying. Would rather the shared places like twitter opened in a new tab (can do this with middle-click, mind you).

Comment: The only part of this we can really control is the new tab.  The Twitter behavior is up to Twitter...

Comment: @David, the new tab would make it much better. Its not so much losing the link being carried over if you aren't logged in, its going back and fourth just trying to promote a link while finding where you were on Area 51 in the first place :)

Comment: Hmm .. I'm not seeing any share feature on Area 51, but I'm also blocked from Twitter, FB, et al.  

What about a simple share-by-email form?   This is especially important for growing communities in non-computing domains.  The folks I'd like introduce don't do FB or tweet but do know a lot about some of the subject areas and would want to belong.

Answer (score 2):

We can't do anything about Twitter's poor handling of this, and I don't like forcing links to open in a new tab/window (though I could be persuaded)

Comment: Its not so earth shatteringly important that I'd push hard for it. The only time its a problem is if you aren't logged into the service that you selected for sharing. Still, I did not expect to be taken away from area51 after sharing, especially when I had more that I wanted to do on the page that I was sharing. I'm not saying its 'wrong', its just different than how every other site I can think of does it, so I guess I'm used to different behavior. Opening the links in a new tab manually fixes the problem.